# Why am I recieving key error after slicing my data?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a code that slices data and then suppose to calculte different indices according to the columns.

My code worked well but today I had to slice differently the data and since then I get keyerror whenever I try to compute the indices.

unfortinatly I can't share my original data but I hope this code can help in understand what happenned here.

This is my code with some explainations:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df_plants = pd.read_csv('my_data')

#My data contains columns with numerical data and their column title is numbers
#here I have changed the numbers titles into float 
float_cols = [float(i) for i in df_plants.columns.tolist()[4:] if type(i)==str]
df_plants.columns.values[4:] = float_cols

#detector edges removal
#Here my goal is to remove some of the columns that has wrong data.
#this part was added today and might be the reason for the problem
cols = df_plants.columns.tolist()
df_plants=df_plants[cols[:4] + cols[11:]].copy()

#Trying to calculte indices:
filter_plants['NDVI']=(filter_plants['801.03']-filter_plants['680.75'])/(filter_plants['801.03']+filter_plants['680.75'])
```

**KeyError: '801.03'**

In order to solve this problem I have tried to add this line again before the calculation:

```
float_cols = [float(i) for i in df_plants.columns.tolist()[4:] ]
df_plants.columns.values[4:] = float_cols
```

but I still got the keyerror.

My end goal is to be able to do calculations with my indices which I believe relate to changing in the type of the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the last line to:

```
filter_plants['NDVI']=(filter_plants[801.03]-filter_plants[680.75])/(filter_plants[801.03]+filter_plants[680.75])
```